# Trying to implement SSL on the Jersey client in order to talk to a secure server

Tags: java, ssl, jersey, webservices-client

I'm following the example atb the end of chapter 3 in Sunil Gulabani's *Developing RESTful Web Services with Jersey 2.0"* Here's the code:

```
SSLContext sslContext = null;

   try {
       sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
   } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext).build();
```

The error I get is:

```
SSLContextImpl is not initialized
```

I certainly do initialize `SSLContext`, but `SSLContext` behaves like a regular class and not like an interface. So, what is `SSLContextImpl`.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call `SSLContext.init()` with appropriate parameters.